# How to combine time series measured in multiple experiments?

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, descriptive-statistics, stationarity, variability

I have recorded neural activity over time in mice while they perform a task.  There are several mice, each ran different numbers of sessions, and repeated the task different numbers of times each session.

There are likely nonstationarities, both within a session as the subject fatigues, and across sessions as subjects learn the task, acclimate to conditions, happens to be hungry that day, etc.  There are also likely differences across subjects.  And certainly the neural activity has strong temporal correlations.

For starters, I want to ignore these problems and just show a summary of something like "the average time course of activity," and its variability.  What do you recommend, just averaging everything together?  What about representing the variability?  I don't want to assume the variability is Gaussian, can I do better than just showing some inner percentile range?  I guess a bootstrap CI of the mean?  I am worried that the size of the latter will be misleadingly small, because altogether there are many trials.

Is it bad practice to show such a summary without any checking for effects of session / subject / etc?

If you did want to start worrying about effects of session / subject, or nonstationarity within session, how would you proceed?  What criteria justify grouping data like these?  I am wary of tests that amount to "I didn't collect enough data to conclude there was a difference, so I grouped it."

Is there a term for this type of problem?

Comment: Please use correct English grammar, punctuation, capitalization, etc.

Comment: found some papers about multi level analysis / mixed models (how do those two relate?) -- sounds like they address this problem, is that right?  http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v17/n4/full/nn.3648.html http://scan.oxfordjournals.org/content/2/3/251.full